# Deleting the Core Data Generated sqlite3 file

Tags: ios

I am trying to delete the Core Data generated sqlite3 file for testing purposes in tear down.

Core Data creates the file using the following path.

```
/Users/mehreen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/62BB2C13-6640-408E-B2B9-0247473E24B4/data/Containers/Data/Application/**8507624D-3A06-4EEC-9C0D-2AAF328E43B6**/Library/Application Support
```

In my integration test I have the following code to delete the sqlite file in tear down method.

```
static func rollbackDatabase() {
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        
        let applicationSupportUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        let applicationSupportPath = applicationSupportUrl.path
        
        do {
            let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: applicationSupportPath!)
            for fileName in fileNames {
                let filePath = "\(String(describing: applicationSupportPath))/\(fileName)"
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it points to the path

```
/Users/mehreen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/62BB2C13-6640-408E-B2B9-0247473E24B4/data/Containers/Data/Application/**FEB3A60C-CDC0-4D59-AF67-6D1723C01B1D**/Library/Application Support
```

which is different from the original Core Data file path. So on that path there are no files to delete. How can I get the same path as used by Core Data to the sqlite files in my test environment.

Comment: Use databaseUrl.path

Comment: The problem is that if I even use databaseUrl.path then I get a different path due to the UUID component in the path.

Comment: It is the application id which changed. Did you make any change in info.plist about application or bundle name ? On the simulator you must have 2 different app.

Comment: For some reason, it automatically installs the app 2 times. One of them can be launched (real app) and the other one I believe is meant for the testing.